# PNG images resized via wordpress, are losing some shades of gray

Tags: php, wordpress, image, imagemagick

I'm posting here instead of wordpress.stackexchange because this might not have be wordpress issue but more of an image or imagemagick settings issue.

I'm using some js to swap src urls to responsively load images.

```
<?php 
    $imageID = $feat['image'];
    $alt = $imageID['alt'];
    $mobile = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imageID['id'],'mobile-feature');
    $tablet = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imageID['id'],'tablet-feature');
    $laptop = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imageID['id'],'laptop-feature');
    $desktop = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imageID['id'],'desktop-feature'); 
?>
<img src="<?php echo $mobile[0]; ?>" 
height=" " width=" " 
data-maxwidth768px="<?php echo $mobile[0]; ?>" 
data-maxwidth1000px="<?php echo $tablet[0]; ?>" 
data-maxwidth1500px="<?php echo $laptop[0]; ?>" 
data-minwidth1501px="<?php echo $desktop[0]; ?>" 
alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" title="<?php echo $alt; ?>" />
```

The images it pulls are the ones that are resized by wordpress.

I've check my php install and I am using ImageMagick instead of GD, I am aware that wordpress as of 3.5 (I am on 3.9) will fallback to GD if imagick cannot be found.

[image: imagick screenshot]

I am aware that a lot of my images have transparency but it seems even higher contrast grays are still being lost.

Here are the normal and resized images being created by wordpress.

Normal:
[image: non-reszied]

Resized:
[image: resized]

Notice how some of the gray pins have been cut?

Normal:
[image: non-resized]

Resized:
[image: resized]

Notice the difference here too.

I have am using the wordpress function `add_image_size()` to create these sizes whilst keeping image (jpeg) quality as high as possible.

```
add_image_size( 'mobile-feature', 320 );
add_image_size( 'tablet-feature', 400 );
add_image_size( 'laptop-feature', 600 );
add_image_size( 'desktop-feature', 800 );

add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', 'tgm_image_full_quality' );
add_filter( 'wp_editor_set_quality', 'tgm_image_full_quality' );
/**
 * Filters the image quality for thumbnails to be at the highest ratio possible.
 *
 * Supports the new 'wp_editor_set_quality' filter added in WP 3.5.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param int $quality The default quality (90)
 * @return int $quality Amended quality (100)
 */
function tgm_image_full_quality( $quality ) {

    return 100;

}
```

Yet still the resized images leave a lot to be desired.

When saving my images as jpegs everything works fine, of course, as there's no transparency.

But no matter what settings I use to save my PNG in photoshop it always has the same result.

My photoshop settings.

- PNG-24

  Transparency

  Interlaced

  Convert to sRGB

  Quality Bicubic

What can I do to stop this?

Comment: The way pins are clipped according to the underlying world map suggests it is entirely to do with transparency rather than your quality setting. I don't have your environment to replicate anything, but I would try removing `Interlaced` as that only complicates things, and also "pre-flattening" your images yourself in Photoshop prior to saving and making sure they look correct there.

Comment: Yea I figured as much. I'll give it a go thanks :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell wont I lose transparency if I flatten the image?

Comment: Oh, we may be coming to the problem then.... you should not lose transparency when you flatten in Photoshop - that will only happen if some of your layers are opaque which will cause the problems you are having.

Comment: Ok, I just did a test - you are right - flattening does make your image opaque - have a try with `Merge Visible` before saving.

Comment: Cool, at least I think I'm getting closer to a solution :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't have the option to merge visible. It's part of a larger psd and it's been grouped so I duplicate group into a new document, merge group and crop. I'm not sure what other options to take.

Comment: When you create the new document, do you set the `Background Contents` to Transparent?

Comment: Mmm, I don't get that option. When I click duplicate group, I just the option of destination->new.

Comment: Maybe you can do File->New in Photoshop and create a new empty document with the same size as your existing document but select "Background=Transparent" then go to your original document and copy the layers/groups you want and paste them into the new empty document and try from there...